# Max Call Stack exceeded in Binary Search Python

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, binary-search, callstack

I am trying to implement Binary Search in Python with recursion.

I write code above:

```
space = [i for i in range(4096)]

# Recursive:
def binarySearchRec(arr, low, high, target):
    if high >= low:
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] > target:
            return binarySearchRec(arr, low, mid-1, target)
        else:
            return binarySearchRec(arr, mid, high, target)
    else:
        return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    element = random.choice(space)
    print(f"Index: {binarySearchRec(space, 0, len(space)-1, element)} | Number: {element}")
```

This should return answer in max 12 steps because O(log(N)) complexity. But some runs it exceeds max call stack. How can i prevent this i can't find why.

I will be preciate for an answer.

Hey Guys thank you for answers,

I also found a solution to problem. Every time target > arr[mid]
i was returning low = mid. I changed this as low = mid + 1.

This solved the problem and it's worked as it opposed to last element found in 13 steps as it is supposed to be.

Code:

```
def binarySearchRec(arr, low, high, target):
    if high >= low:
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] > target:
            return binarySearchRec(arr, low, mid-1, target)
        else:
            return binarySearchRec(arr, mid+1, high, target)
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: note `list(range(4096))` is the proper way to write `[i for i in range(4096)]`

Answer (score 1):

Your function works, except in the case where variable 'high' is one above 'low', and the target is equal to the high variable. This is because high >= low is true, but mid rounds down to low, which is not equal to target. You could add:

```
if high - 1 == low:
    if arr[low] == target:
        return low
    return high
```

before or after the `if high >= low:` line. Also, you don't need to call arr[x], because arr[x] == x, so arr[x] evaluates to x and you can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Off-by-one errors are hard to debug in problems like this one. You have two issues -

1. When `target` is less than `arr[mid]`, the sub-problem is `low, mid`
2. When `target` is greater than `arr[mid]`, the sub-problem is `mid + 1, high`

I find it helps to write the `<` condition and the `>` condition. If neither of those conditions are met, then `==` is by default the `else` condition.

```py
def binary_search(arr, target, low, high):
  if low >= high:
    return -1
  else:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if target < arr[mid]:
      return binary_search(arr, target, low, mid)       #1
    elif target > arr[mid]:
      return binary_search(arr, target, mid + 1, high)  #2
    else:
      return mid                                        # target == arr[mid]
```

```py
def search(sorted_arr, q):
  return binary_search(sorted_arr, q, 0, len(sorted_arr))
```

```py
foo = list(range(1000000))
print(search(foo, 523407))
```

```py
523407
```

Note for this particular problem, you do not have to expand `range` into a `list`. If you are actually searching a `range`, this can save a considerable amount of memory. This is because Python ranges allow you to access elements directly using `[]`, just like lists -

```py
bar = range(1000000)
print(search(bar, 683495)) # pass in range directly
```

```py
683495
```